# How can EditText occupy all the remaining space in a layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a linear layout (linear2 in code) with horizontal orientation.
I've placed a button, editText and a second button into this layout.
I'd like to have the button's width as "wrap_content".
How do I give all the remaining space to editText without using weight?
Is it possible to place this layout to the bottom without using weight
of vertical views?

Code is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/backNormal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="12">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonClip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="5"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonProcess"
            android:text='Process'
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: If you achieved your requirement using LinearLayout then you have to use weight.

Comment: There's button next to EditText, so how can it occupy rest of the space? Would you please post the image of your requirement?

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try relativeLayout to place editview to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

Here i try to improve your LinearLayout weight allocation

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/backNormal"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.85">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buttonClip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonProcess"
            android:text='Process'
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes! You helped me again. Thanks again! I understand the trick! You've just changed the button width to "wrap_content" and removed weith, but other views in this layout have weight. Hah! I didn't know about such approach!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Keep your Edittext hight wrap_content.....that's it.

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editChatMessage"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top|left"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:layout_gravity= "center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        />
```